# firefox connection was reset error for a long REST API request

Tags: firefox

I have a RESTful web api which takes 5 minutes to respond a JSON response message. In firefox (version 32.0.3), I get a "The connection was reset" error after 2 to 3 minutes. When I call my call my API in Chrome, there is no error and I get the intended response after 5 minutes. 
I have tried the following without any luck: 
1. tweaking timeout values in about:config 
2. clearing browser caches 
3. setting "No proxy" in network settings 
4. disabling ad-ons and starting in safe mode.
5. Try with old firefox versions: 22 and 28

Any clues as to why this is working in chrome but not in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the attribute executionTimeout="1200" to the  tag in  configuration section